# How to solved error "Invalid default value for <field> " in django

Tags: python, django

I using django framework to devlop my site. When i running on development server with sqlite database. database   migrate everything work well.

but i got a problem when i running on production server with mysql database. in console is running OK in few line then display error "Invalid default value for 'state'". what happend to got this error.

this is my model in models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ref_order = models.CharField(max_length=25,verbose_name="ref_code")
    member = models.ForeignKey('Member',on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="member")
    order_product = models.ManyToManyField('OrderProduct',verbose_name="order_product")
    reciver_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,verbose_name="reciver")
    reciver_location = models.CharField(max_length=30,verbose_name="reciver location")
    submit_order = models.BooleanField(default=False,verbose_name="order submit")
    evidence = models.FileField(upload_to='slip',null=True,verbose_name="evidence transfer")
    money_transfer = models.FloatField(null=True,verbose_name="money")
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False,verbose_name="verified transfer")
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name="state")
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name="create at")
    payment_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True,verbose_name="transfer_data")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "state" column has a max_length of 500. For most of the Databases, this limit is 255. If you need to use a value of more than 255, you should try TextField instead of CharField.

Comment: thank for answer. 

first i set max_length=30 it error . then i tried max_length=100 got error same. then i tried max_legth=500. but i fogot set to first

Comment: In your migrations, have you defined a default value for the "state"' field?

Answer (score 0):

@devnext- It's not a good practice using a different Database provider in development and a different one in production. Use the same database provider across all your deployments. In that way, you can avoid some of these issues.